# how can i update multiple rows with one query using mybatis and hashmap data type?

Tags: sql, hashmap, mybatis

I fetch modified data like below.

```
datatype : hashmap with <string, object> 

{params=[ETC:AUTH:null CHK:0    NUM:A10000  PHONE:11    GENDER:M    ID:A10000   DEP:PL  
NAME:John   USEABLE:Y   , ETC:  AUTH:null   CHK:0   NUM:A20000  PHONE:123   GENDER:M    
ID:A20000   DEP:Market  NAME:Phillips   USEABLE:Y   ]}
```

it consist of modified row's all column. not only modified column.

and I want update all rows in params at once. using mybatis

```
<update id="modifyData" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
UPDATE tableName
SET 
    <foreach collection="params" item="one_row" ...>
    ...
    WHERE ID = #{one_row.id}
    </foreach>
```

how can I do this successfully?